# Http code 204 returns while hosting on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, http, heroku, https, minecraft

I try to send any request to my API from ReactJs application. Localy it's work fine but on Heroku any request returns 204 code. If I try manualy get response from requested string, It's also returns correct result. [image: Bad response]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add the code which performs the API call

Comment: @Nick Parsons, added image

Answer (score 0):

[image: HTTP GET]

It doesn't work because you aren't doing a HTTP GET request. 
You are doing HTTP OPTIONS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Attached image shows how it can be done.

Comment: Localy UI creates two requests: first - OPTIONS and returns 204 code, second - GET and returns correct response.